# Windows 8.1 wouldn't upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a windows 10 virtual machine on VirtualBox.
It doesn't show "build 10240" and now i can't upgrade my windows 8.1 computer to windows 10.

I didn't see the windows 10 icon so i downloaded a program from CNET: "How to get the Windows 10 upgrade icon if it's missing" and i registered my upgrade but when it came out i didn't got it.

Windows Update says "You will get a message when the upgrade can be installed on this pc."
I contacted microsoft and they said "you should get the update the next few hours" but i didn't get the update.

I tried to contact Microsoft today but the waiting time is too long and becomes longer and longer...

I downloaded a tool on http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 and it doesn't want to open at all.

**EDIT: i still don't have the update!**

Comment: Explain why the downvote please.

Comment: You don't really provide enough information for us to help, so the question isn't all that helpful, to anyone that might have a similar problem since it is unanswerable.  Microsoft is doing a phase roll out for the upgrade, using the media creation tool, is one way to upgrade today instead of waiting.  This phase roll out is also the reason the icon is starting to disappear from machine where it was visible.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some software that is preventing you from upgrading while Windows is running.  As a workaround:

1. Create Windows 10 bootable USB installation media .
2. Configure your BIOS to boot from USB.
3. Boot from the USB installation media.
4. There should have a option to perform an "Upgrade" installation.

Answer (score 0):

> Windows Update says "You will get a message when the upgrade can be installed on this pc."

And you will. They're rolling out the updates over time. Some will get it right away, or have already. Some will have to wait a little while. This is so they can make sure things go smoothly for a smaller group and if there's issues, then most people won't be affected and they can fix it before the rest get to upgrade. It also prevents their servers from being hammered by everyone at once. It spreads out the load over time.